# Stuck at EFI shell, can't boot from USB

Tags: boot, uefi, 32-bit

I'm stuck trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 (Server) on a ZOTAC ZBOX PI320.

It only supports UEFI 32bit, and to use UEFI and Ubuntu you need the 64bit version, which doesn't include a 32bit UEFI.

According to several online guides I included the bootia32.efi (from one of those guides) file in the /EFI/BOOT/ directory of the USB disk.

This worked and I was able to boot the USB disk and began installing ubuntu as usual.

However, during the final part I was prompted to overwrite/delete/replace the UEFI (or something) on the ZBOX, which I did. This failed (with an error message I can't recall) and I decided to start over.

Now I can't boot into anything but the EFI shell (see below) since I formatted the Win8.1 installation, and the USB drive doesn't seem to be registrered at all.

```
EFI Shell version 2.31 [5.8]
Device mapping table
...
<something with block devices>
...
Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh, any other key to continue
Shell>
```

I have seen other people have similar issues, but they still seem to be able to boot either the installation, by typing exit (which in my case just sends me into the BIOS again), or choosing some other boot option in the BIOS (where I have UEFI Shell or disabled as options).

I would really appreciate any clues on what to do?

Comment: Try downloading the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) With any luck, you'll be able to boot to your Ubuntu installation with that. If this works, installing the rEFInd PPA should get you up and running normally; or you may be able to get it to work by manually installing (or perhaps reconfiguring) the EFI version of GRUB.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I was able to boot with rEFInd and then boot the Ubuntu USB installer and reinstall (and now the Ubuntu installation is seen correctly). Aparently one has to be online when doing the install, otherwise it fails with "The grub-efi-ia32 package failed to install into /target/".

Comment: @RodSmith This helped me too, thanks a lot! Why not make it an answer?